Micrometer metric max equals zero when sum is higher than zero
In our project we measure time for outgoing calls to other grpc servers, but I met a situation when a metric _max is zero, but the same metric for _sum is higher than zero.
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@GRpcGlobalInterceptor
public class PsoOutgoingCallsClientInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor, Ordered {

    private static final String METRIC_NAME = "grpc_client";
    private static final String METRIC_TAG_SERVICE = "service";
    private static final String METRIC_TAG_METHOD = "method";
    private static final String METRIC_TAG_ECP_SERVICE_NAME = "ecpName";
    private static final String METRIC_TAG_RESULT = "result";
    private static final String METRIC_TAG_RESULT_OK = "OK";
    private static final String METRIC_TAG_RESULT_ERROR = "ERROR";
    private static final String METRIC_NAME_TEMPLATE = "%s-%s-%s-%s";

    @Value("${ps.metricMinDuration: 1}")
    private long metricMinDuration;
    private final MeterRegistry registry;
    private final Map<String, Timer> timers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }

    public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(final MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> methodDescriptor, final CallOptions callOptions, final Channel channel) {

        var start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        return new ForwardingClientCall.SimpleForwardingClientCall<>(channel.newCall(methodDescriptor, callOptions)) {
            @Override
            public void start(Listener<RespT> responseListener, Metadata headers) {

                super.start(
                        new ForwardingClientCallListener.SimpleForwardingClientCallListener<>(responseListener) {

                            @Override
                            public void onMessage(RespT message) {

                                var res = (com.google.protobuf.Message) message;
                                var end = System.currentTimeMillis();

                                if (res.getDescriptorForType().findFieldByName("info") != null) {

                                    var value = res.getField(res.getDescriptorForType().findFieldByName("info"));

                                    var values = ((DynamicMessage) value).getAllFields();
                                    var resDesc = ((DynamicMessage) value).getDescriptorForType().findFieldByName("result");

                                    if (resDesc != null) {
                                        var messageResult = getServerCallResult(values.get(resDesc).toString());
                                        if (messageResult.equals(ServerCallResult.ERROR)) {
                                            createMetric(METRIC_TAG_RESULT_ERROR, channel.authority(),start, end, methodDescriptor);
                                        } else {
                                            createMetric(METRIC_TAG_RESULT_OK, channel.authority(),start, end, methodDescriptor);
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        createMetric(METRIC_TAG_RESULT_OK, channel.authority(),start, end, methodDescriptor);
                                    }

                                }
                                else {
                                    createMetric(METRIC_TAG_RESULT_OK, channel.authority(),start, end, methodDescriptor);
                                }

                                super.onMessage(message);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onClose(Status status, Metadata trailers) {
                                var end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                if (!status.isOk()) {
                                    createMetric(METRIC_TAG_RESULT_ERROR, channel.authority(), start, end, methodDescriptor);
                                }

                                super.onClose(status, trailers);
                            }
                        },
                        headers);
            }
        };
    }

    private <ReqT, RespT> void createMetric(String callResult,String ecpServiceName, long start, long end, MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> methodDescriptor) {

        var localServiceName = StringUtils.isBlank(methodDescriptor.getServiceName()) ? "" : methodDescriptor.getServiceName();
        var localMethodName = StringUtils.isBlank(methodDescriptor.getBareMethodName()) ? "" : methodDescriptor.getBareMethodName();

        var metricKey = String.format(METRIC_NAME_TEMPLATE, METRIC_NAME, localServiceName, localMethodName, callResult);

        var localTimer = timers.computeIfAbsent(metricKey, t ->
                Timer.builder(METRIC_NAME)
                        .tag(METRIC_TAG_SERVICE, localServiceName)
                        .tag(METRIC_TAG_METHOD, localMethodName)
                        .tag(METRIC_TAG_RESULT, callResult)
                        .tag(METRIC_TAG_ECP_SERVICE_NAME, ecpServiceName)
                        .register(registry)
        );

        var duration = Math.max((end - start), metricMinDuration);

        localTimer.record(duration, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private ServerCallResult getServerCallResult(String potentialResult) {
        try {
            return ServerCallResult.valueOf(potentialResult);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | NullPointerException e) {
            return ServerCallResult.UNKNOWN;
        }

    }

}

I tried many different ways to calculate metrics, even set the minimum duration for a single measure, but in prometheus output i see many rows like this :
grpc_client_seconds_max{ecpName="name_of_the_service",method="ListByGpId",result="OK",service="the_grpc_service_name",} 0.0
grpc_client_seconds_count{ecpName="name_of_the_service",method="ListByGpId",result="OK",service="the_grpc_service_name",} 1.0
grpc_client_seconds_sum{ecpName="name_of_the_service",method="ListByGpId",result="OK",service="the_grpc_service_name",} 0.042

